# Variational formulation mixed BVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm very confused about an exercise and its solution from my course literature, and would really appreciate a explanation on the steps being done in the solution.

So the exercise is to give a variational formulation on the following PDE

$$\begin{cases} -\Delta u(x)=f(x), x \in D \\ \partial_{\nu}u(x)=0, x\in \Gamma_N \\ u(x)=0, x \in \Gamma_D\end{cases}$$

Where $\partial_{\nu}$ denote the normal vector at $\partial D$.

The first step in the solution give is to use Greens formula, but already here things doesn't makes sense to me. It says following:

$$\int \int_D f \phi \ dx = - \int \int_D \Delta u \phi  = -\int_{\partial D} \phi \partial_{\nu} u \ dS + \int \int_D \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \ dx$$

This whole expression doesn't make sense to me and would greatly appreciate if someone would take time to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is just a statement about integration by parts applied to solutions to your BVP.  In particular, for any compactly supported test function $\phi$ and any solution $u$, it follows from Stokes' theorem that

$$ \int_D \nabla\cdot (\phi\nabla u) = \int_D \nabla\phi\cdot\nabla u + \phi\Delta u = \int_{\partial D} \phi \nu\cdot\nabla u. $$

Combining this with the fact that $u$ solves the PDE then yields what you're looking at:

$$ \int_D f\phi = \int_D -\phi \Delta u = \int_D \nabla\phi\cdot\nabla u - \int_{\partial D} \phi\nu\cdot\nabla u.$$

Comment: Where does the two last terms in my expression comes from? It seems like both should be equal to zero from my PDE, so it makes no sense that it would be equal to $f\phi$ to me

Comment: Why should anything be zero here?  The RHS equals $f\phi$ because $-\Delta u = f$.